# Is it possible to set value in different Keras callback?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have custom callback that will reset model weights on some conditions. But this will interfere with EarlyStopping callback saves best monitored value i.e. 'val_loss'. How can I access properties from my custom callback to EarlyStopping callback to set its best 'val_loss' to my value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set in your early stopper:

```
early_stopping_callback.best = new_value
early_stopping_callback.wait = 0
```

Based on the [source code, currently at line 816](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L816)

---

Putting the early stopper inside:

```
class CustomCallback(...):
    def __init__ (....., early_stopper, ...)
        self.early_stopping_callback = early_stopper

    .......

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(...)
custom = CustomCallback(...., early_stopping, ...)
```

You still need to pass both callbacks to `fit`:

```
model.fit(..., callbacks=[custom, early_stopping])
```

Comment: But how to get early_stopping_callback object from inside my custom callback ?

Comment: You don't need to get it inside (You can't if it's a `LambdaCallback`). Just have the variable name. 
If you do want to put it inside a "custom" callback, see answer.